# how to know what the process that connected to my machine VIA specific port

Tags: linux, process, netstat, port, ss

with the following command I want to get which are the IP's that connected on my machine with port 8088

`18.23.292.9` is machine that resource manager service is running on with port 8088

```
ss -tanp | grep 8088 | grep ESTAB
ESTAB      0      0      18.23.292.9:8088               118.2.291.2:52874               users:(("java",pid=13970,fd=829))
ESTAB      0      0      18.23.292.9:8088               110.6.52.2:56379               users:(("java",pid=13970,fd=668))
ESTAB      0      0      18.23.292.9:8088               110.6.52.2:52337               users:(("java",pid=13970,fd=666))
ESTAB      0      0      18.23.292.9:8088               118.2.280:34088               users:(("java",pid=13970,fd=790))
ESTAB      0      0      18.23.292.9:8088               110.6.52.2:59794               users:(("java",pid=13970,fd=660))
ESTAB      0      0      18.23.292.9:8088               110.6.52.2:59415               users:(("java",pid=13970,fd=665))
ESTAB      0      0      18.23.292.9:8088               118.2.279:53610               users:(("java",pid=13970,fd=750))
ESTAB      0      0      18.23.292.9:8088               110.6.52.2:63875               users:(("java",pid=13970,fd=661))
ESTAB      0      0      18.23.292.9:8088               110.6.52.2:50267               users:(("java",pid=13970,fd=667))
```

now I want to know which are the application/services on remote machines are actually connected to port 8088

the reason is that we saw many connection to port 8088 and we want to know which are the process that try to connect

the machines are as below example `118.2.291.2` ,  `110.6.52.2` , etc

meanwhile I create without success the following script , that capture the IP and port of the machines that are connected

```
#!/bin/bash


port=`  netstat -anp | grep :8088 | grep ESTAB | head -1 | awk '{print $5}' | sed s'/:/ /g' | awk '{print $2}' ` ; IP=` netstat -nape | grep $port | awk '{print $5}' | sed s'/:/ /g' | awk '
{print $1}' `
export PORT=` netstat -nape | grep $port | awk '{print $5}' | sed s'/:/ /g' | awk '{print $2}' `

echo $IP
echo $PORT
```

***maybe other good example***

here is a good example how find out which process is currently using a certain port in Linux. and also we get the list of machines that are connected ( on the right side )

```
lsof -i tcp:8088
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    13970   yarn  396u  IPv4 1052681821      0t0  TCP *:radan-http (LISTEN)
java    13970   yarn  559u  IPv4 1201044836      0t0  TCP master02.bigdata130.cgnt:radan-http->worker01.TATA130.cgnt:47506 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13970   yarn  617u  IPv4 1201044953      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master03.TATA130.com:33736 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13970   yarn  621u  IPv4 1200925788      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master01.TATA130.com:37762 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13970   yarn  631u  IPv4 1201038517      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master02.TATA130.com:56258 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13970   yarn  634u  IPv4 1201046323      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master02.TATA130.com:56272 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13970   yarn  635u  IPv4 1201038518      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master02.TATA130.com:56270 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13970   yarn  664u  IPv4 1201049689      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->kafka03.TATA130.com:39486 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13970   yarn  693u  IPv4 1201050710      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->worker02.TATA130.com:39090 (ESTABLISHED)
java    18394 ambari 1511u  IPv4 1201046322      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:56258->master02.TATA130.com:radan-http (ESTABLISHED)
java    18394 ambari 1515u  IPv4 1201049634      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:56270->master02.TATA130.com:radan-http (ESTABLISHED)
java    18394 ambari 1516u  IPv4 1201008383      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:41112->master01.TATA130.com:radan-http (ESTABLISHED)
java    18394 ambari 1517u  IPv4 1201038519      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:56272->master02.TATA130.com:radan-http (ESTABLISHED)
```

it will be very useful also if we know which is the user of the PID that used the port on target machines

for example

```
java    13970   yarn  617u  IPv4 1201044953      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master03.TATA130.com:33736 (ESTABLISHED) PID=32424  user=root
java    13970   yarn  621u  IPv4 1200925788      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master01.TATA130.com:37762 (ESTABLISHED) PID=324424 user=yarn
java    13970   yarn  631u  IPv4 1201038517      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master02.TATA130.com:56258 (ESTABLISHED) PID=324224 user=yarn
```

or maybe by this explain as

lets take the line

```
java    13970   yarn  617u  IPv4 1201044953      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master03.TATA130.com:33736 (ESTABLISHED)
```

so on master03 machine the port is 33736

so if we access to master03 machine and do

```
 netstat -nlp | grep :33736

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33736            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13970/java
```

and

```
ps -ef | grep 13970 |  grep -v grep |  awk '{print $1}'
yarn
```

so my question is - can we use the command  `lsof -i tcp:8088` , with pipe to other commands that gives us the expected results , or maybe other idea as script?

***Expected results***

```
java    13970   yarn  617u  IPv4 1201044953      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master03.TATA130.com:33736 (ESTABLISHED) PID=32424  user=root
java    13970   yarn  621u  IPv4 1200925788      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master01.TATA130.com:37762 (ESTABLISHED) PID=324424 user=yarn
java    13970   yarn  631u  IPv4 1201038517      0t0  TCP master02.TATA130.com:radan-http->master02.TATA130.com:56258 (ESTABLISHED) PID=324224 user=yarn
```

Comment: `fuser -v -n tcp 8088` `fuser -v -n tcp 0`

Comment: `ss -o state connected src :8088` `lsof -i @0.0.0.0:8088 -n -P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it the other way round.

I assume

- you can connect to remote hosts,
- and remote hosts is unix.

just run

```
ss -tanp | awk '$5 == "18.23.292.9:8088"'
```

on remote hosts.

- assuming also that no NAT is set

Comment: about the command -->  lsof -i tcp:8088
 , dose this cli gives real output about who are the machines that are connected to port 8088 ?